# OpenVPN - can't connect to clients on a new subnet

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, subnet

I run a server with lots of clients connected to it via OpenVPN and the number of clients slowly grew until it reached over 255 a few days ago. When I was initially setting up the VPN, I had this in mind and set the subnet mask to '255.255.0.0'; nevertheless, something is amiss, as I can connect to old clients with `10.8.0.x` IP addresses, but not any new clients with `10.8.1.x` IP addresses.

Am I missing anything in my configs?

- `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

  ```ini
  port 1194
  proto udp
  dev tun

  ca ca.crt
  crl-verify crl.pem
  cert server.crt
  key server.key
  dh dh.pem

  auth SHA512
  tls-auth ta.key 0
  cipher AES-256-CBC

  topology subnet
  server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
  ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

  push "bypass-dhcp"
  push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
  push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
  push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"

  keepalive 10 120
  sndbuf 0
  rcvbuf 0
  persist-key
  persist-tun

  verb 3

  log /var/log/openvpn.log
  status openvpn-status.log

  # This automatically assigns domain names to clients, based on their names:
    # NOTE: You have to comment out user and grop lines above for this to even work
      #user nobody
      #group nogroup

      # default is 1 which doesn't allow user-defined scripts
      script-security 2
      learn-address /home/dvida/openvpn_scripts/learn_address.sh
  ```
- `/etc/openvpn/client-common.txt`:

  ```ini
  client
  dev tun
  proto udp
  remote blah.blah.com 1194

  sndbuf 0
  rcvbuf 0
  mssfix 1160

  resolv-retry infinite
  persist-key
  persist-tun
  nobind

  remote-cert-tls server
  tls-version-min 1.0
  key-direction 1

  auth SHA512
  cipher AES-256-CBC

  verb 3
  ```
- `ifconfig` reports this VPN interface has no IP conflicts with other interfaces:

  ```bsh
  tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
            inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.0.0
            UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:71105670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:70755978 errors:0 dropped:391 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
            RX bytes:42092973453 (39.2 GiB)  TX bytes:42070922921 (39.1 GiB)
  ```

Comment: You're missing the subnet mask in the `push dhcp-option dns`; have you tried adding `push route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0`? Also, the config is inefficient _(tuned config [example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN))__: AES128 will remain uncrackable until at least 2030, so AES256 isn't providing any additional security, but is massively slowing throughput; v2.4 doesn't appear to be being used due to `tls-auth` - `tls-crypt` supersedes and is more efficient; TLS isn't being used - v2.4 added support for EC TLS ciphers, which are more efficient than SSL ciphers.

Comment: Thank you! I added the subnets and the push route command, so now that portion of the config file looks like this: 
`push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8 255.255.0.0"`
`push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4 255.255.0.0"`
`push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1 255.255.0.0" # Push the DNS server`
`push route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0`
Nevertheless, after restarting the openvpn server, nothing changed. 10.8.1.x clients are still not accessible.

Comment: You only want to add the subnet masks to RFC1918 IPs _(e.g. private addresses that aren't WAN accessible, as your Google DNS will likely no longer work)_. I know it has to do with routing, but I've never used OpenVPN where it spans multiple subnets. Until someone else chimes in, you may want to review the OpenVPN 2.4 man page to see if that helps in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was not OpenVPN related and was
with this SNAT rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 129.100.40.167
```

- I updated the live `iptables` rule and fixed the one in `/etc/rc.local` so the netmask is `/16` instead of `/24`